# MSBuild XmlPeek task help required

Tags: msbuild, readxml

My sample.xml file is below

```
<deployment>
     <definition type="xpath">
      <xpath>configuration/Settings/add[@key='NetworkPath'][@value]</xpath>
  <attribute>value</attribute>
  <value>http://www.google.com</value>
 </definition>
</deployment>
```

I want to fetch the value "http://www.google.com" corresponsing to xpath "configuration/Settings/add[@key='NetworkPath'][@value]". I am writing below XmlPeek task but it is not working

```
 <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="C:\Sample.xml"
         Query="configuration/Settings/add[@key='NetworkPath'][@value]">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
</XmlPeek>
<Message Text="Peeked value is @(Peeked)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some confusion about XPath.

If you want to retrieve htttp://www.google.com from Sample.xml you need to apply this query:

```
<XmlPeek XmlInputPath="Sample.xml"
         Query="/deployment/definition/value/text()">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
</XmlPeek>
```

If you want to extract the path `configuration/Settings/add[@key='NetworkPath'][@value]/@value` it corresponds to another Xml file having this form:

```
<configuration>
    <Settings>
        <add key="NetworkPath" value="http://www.google.com"/> 
    </Settings>
</configuration>
```

Check out some [XPath examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I understood what you mean.

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I understood what you mean. The way I want is correctly being fetched by third Party tool "Final Builder". so, i thought there must be a way to do same with msbuild. Let's see if someone else has answer or a way to do this

Comment: You can do it with msbuild but you need to change the XmlInputPath and use the real xml file instead of "Sample.xml"